# Change system tray color in Windows Phone app through c# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I know I can change the system tray color through xaml using this:

```
 shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="#D2D9AE"
```

but what if I want to change the system tray color through c#? Is there any way to change the foreground / background color of systemtray through c# code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the properties. e.g.:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Phone.Shell.SystemTray.BackgroundColor = Colors.Cyan;
    Microsoft.Phone.Shell.SystemTray.ForegroundColor = Colors.Green;
}
```

Comment: I copied your code but it didnt recognize it. Do I need a special reference to use it?

Comment: make sure you're calling this method and the SystemTray for the page is visible. Upated answer to show triggering Loaded handler.

Comment: I know how to trigger the Loaded handler! I did everything you did, but with no success. Let me post a screenshot to show you

Comment: I just took a brand new project (targetting 8.0) and added in the above and it worked for me.

Comment: @user1924391 I've explicitly stated the namespace now. It's not included by default in WP7.1